# Reactjs cropping an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, canvas

Right now what I'm trying to do is have a user upload an image, crop it to fit the dimensions I need, then take that new image and upload it to my server.

I'm using react-image-crop for cropping, and I am able to do so, however, when I try to get the new image, it shows up as all black. I can't use pixel dimensions so I am using the percent crop that the package provides.

Here is my function that takes in the original base64 image, creates an invisible canvas with the new dimensions, turns the canvas into another base64 image, and returns it.

```
export function getCroppedImage(image64, crop, extension) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = image64;
  canvas.width = crop.width * image.width * 0.01;
  canvas.height = crop.height * image.height * 0.01;
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * image.width * 0.01,
      crop.y * image.height * 0.01,
      crop.width * image.width * 0.01,
      crop.height * image.height * 0.01,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width * image.width * 0.01,
      crop.height * image.height * 0.01
    );
  };
  if (crop.width !== 0) return canvas.toDataURL("image/" + extension);
}
```

This will return the correct dimensions, and is able to read the original image fine, but the content of the new image appears black and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: What's with all the * 0.01?

Comment: the percentages are like 58% not 0.58. I solved the issue though

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I wasn't actually displaying the canvas in the markup. Didn't know it had to be shown in order for the dataURL to be created properly

Comment: Could you please update the finished function with showing the canvas ? THanks!